# Compile Error With Generic Method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

EDIT:  I found out that I can get it to compile if I cast the IMetadataType object to the TMetadata type.  Why do I need to do this?

EDIT #2:  The "Values" property is a .NET dictionary of type <TMetadata, TData>.

I have this generic method:

```
private void FillMetadata<TMetadata, TData>
    (Metadata<TMetadata, TData> oMetadata) where TMetadata : IMetadataType
{
    IMetadataType o;
    oMetadata.Values.Add(o, (TData)(object)GetValue());
}
```

I have stripped the implementation to simplify it (I actually use a real object, not the IMetadataType declared here).

My question is, why doesn't this compile?  The compile error is on the Add() method:  "cannot convert from 'IMetadataType' to 'TMetadata'."  Isn't that what the "where" clause on the method is for?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where TMetadata : IMetadataType` is a constraint for the generic type parameter `TMetadata` saying it should derive from `IMetadataType`. Since `oMetadata` knows only `TMetadata` and `TData` as types to work with, you have to use them in your methods body. This should work:

```
private void FillMetadata<TMetadata, TData>(Metadata<TMetadata, TData> oMetadata) 
    where TMetadata : IMetadataType
{
    TMetadata o;
    oMetadata.Values.Add(o, (TData)(object)GetValue());
}
```

Comment: I see the problem now.  What I'm trying to do is like trying to add a base class object to a list of derived class objects, right?  Obviously, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

How is the .Add method declared?

Ok, if the .Add method expects a TMetadata, you can't expect it to take a IMetadataType, since you say that TMetadata is a IMetadataType, not the other way around.

Basically, for all the compiler knows, you can be trying to add something entirely different than a TMetadata, and the fact that you implement a common interface doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, the "Values" property is a dictionary of type <TMetadata, TData>.

Comment: Thanks.  You mean I still can't do this even though the Metadata class also has the same where clause on the class?